# Python Arithmetic Operators

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any module or library where one get list of all arithmetic operators in Python?

eg:- from string module we can get all letters as

```
>>>string.ascii_lowercase
>>>'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Has python something like

```
some_module.operators
```

which can give result below ???

```
'+-/*^)'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Python module called [Operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) but it doesn't appear to have what you want.

Anyway, [here's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) a list with all the Python operators.